# How to call Post method on DropDownList selection in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, postback

can anyone please help me about how to invoke a post method on changing the drop down list selection?
I have Index method in my controller which takes me to index page. There i have placed a dropdown list using Html.Dropdown containing items like 1,2,3,etc.
I want to call post method for Index whenever i makes any selection from the dropdown.

regards,
kapil

Comment: ignore my ans ! i missed the mvc part ! *blush*

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using JQuery

```
 <select id="idXYZ" name="XYZ" onchange="SetUnit(this.value)">
 <%=  ViewData["YourValue"]%>
</select>
```

Now use JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetUnit(unit) {
        $.post("/Admin/YourMethod?itemid=" + unit.toString(), function(data) {
            var data = eval('(' + data + ')');
            $("#idunit").html(data.Value);
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: If you are not using Jquery then use Ajax post method directly//POST http.open("POST", url, true);

Comment: Thanks Pankaj,

but instead of <select>, i have used <%=Html.DropDownList...>.
Then i did the same as you have said above. But unfortunately it's not working for me.

Comment: @@Kapil you are not using JQuey that's why your  $.post is not working.Please use ajax post. see this article to use ajax post
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/12/ajax-post-method-example-using-javascript-jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you using JQuery?  You could use $.post to post your data in the onchange event...  I think in the web forms way it was using a _doPostBack call in the onchange event if you set AutoPostBack to true... not 100% sure about that.

HTH

Comment: Thanks Brian.
I am using Javascript to handle onchange event. How can i do so there?

Comment: try doing _doPostBack('<Select element name>', '<command>') and see if that works.  That is a part of the MS Ajax framework and so you need to reference that.